# Flutter local notifications, but with different notifications

Tags: flutter

i m trying to make an app with notifications which display daily notifications to the user. I m using local notification plugin, everything is working but it repeat the same notification again and again, for me i want to show different notification each day.

```
Future<void> showNotification(int id, String title, String body) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      RepeatInterval
          .everyMinute, //schedule the notification to show after 2 seconds.
      const NotificationDetails(
        // Android details
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
            channelDescription: "notfi",
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max),
        // iOS details
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'default.wav',
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
        ),
      ),

      // Type of time interpretation
      androidAllowWhileIdle:
          true, // To show notification even when the app is closed
    );
  }
```

Here is my code for schedule notification daily

```
String? randomName;
    final random = new Random();
    randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
```

Here i randomize a list from where i want to get random string from it. I don' t know why it s not updating every day.

```
 onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showToast();
                        NotificationService().showNotification(
                          1,
                          '$randomNames${widget.userPost}',
                          randomName!,
                        );
                      });
                    },
```

Here is where i call the notifications, it s working, but it get me the same notification over and over again.

Anybody know how to solve this?

I've tried with setState

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you have to use zoneSchedule, and loop for the notifications you want to get and also set the date of receipt.

Here is my code :

```
scheduleNotification(
      DateTime date, String title, String description, int id) async {
    var tzDateNotif = tz.TZDateTime.from(date, tz.local);
    await _localNotificationService.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      description,
      tzDateNotif,
      const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'your channel id', 'your channel description')),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    );
  }
```

And for the loop you can do like this :

```
var notifications = [
    {
      "title": "title1", 
      "description": "description 1",
      "date" : "the date that you want to receive the 1st notif",
      "id": "id1"
    },
    {
      "title": "title2", 
      "description": "description 2",
      "date" : "the date that you want to receive the 2nd notif",
      "id": "id2"
    },
    {
      "title": "title3", 
      "description": "description 3",
      "date" : "the date that you want to receive the 3rd notif",
      "id": "id3"
    },
    {
      "title": "title4", 
      "description": "description 4",
      "date" : "the date that you want to receive the 4th notif",
      "id": "id4"
    },
  ];

for (var notif in notifications) {
  localNotificationService.scheduleNotification(
            notif["date"], notif["title"], notif["description"], notif["id"]);
}
```

For the id it must be different for each notification.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the loop? I don t understand what i have to do if you can tell me, thx

Comment: I edited my answer. So in fact you have to define a list of notifications that you want to have, with the date of receipt and schedule them using zoneSchedule.

Comment: Thx, this is working fine, but here is another problem, i have a list with over 400 strings and it s a nightmare trying to do this with this example. How can i update the randomName! without pressing the button cause i see it only update another string only if i press the button, but i want to press the button just one time.